# How to append random number to a list

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function to generate random number:

```
drawFloat :: Float -> Float -> IO Float
drawFloat x y = getStdRandom (randomR (x,y))
```

Now I have a list `[1,2,3]`.

How can I append the random number to this list?

I tried `[1,2,3] ++ (drawFloat 2 10)` It did not work...

ERROR Message:

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘IO a0’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:72:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(drawFloat 2 10)’
    In the expression: [1, 2, 3] ++ (drawFloat 2 10)
```

I also tried `[1,2,3] ++ [(drawFloat 2 10)]`. Still not work..

Comment: `drawFloat 2 10 >>= \x -> return ([1,2,3] ++ [x])` or `(\x -> [1,2,3] ++ [x]) <$> drawFloat 2 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the type of `drawFloat` is `Float -> Float -> IO Float`. We can only append a `[Float]`. Try

```
 appendRand :: [Float] -> IO [Float]
 appendRand lis = (lis ++) . return <$> drawFloat 2 10
```

Here we are elevating the function `(list ++) . return :: Float -> [Float]` to a `IO Float -> IO [Float]` which is exactly what we want. (Here, `return` is operating on the `[]` monad, not `IO`)

Comment: Hi what if I want to append a list of random number to a normal list. How can I do this? For example: a normal list `[]` appends a random list `[1,2,3]`(these numbers generated by function drawFloat)?

Comment: @CSnerd if you want to append a list of random numbers, you could make a function that generates the random list, like `randList = mapM (const $ rawFloat 2 10) [1..n]` and then append that like `(lis ++) <$> randList`

Comment: @CSnerd `randGrid :: Int -> Float -> IO [Int]`, `randGrid n p = (mapM . mapM) (const $ singleRandP p) $ (replicate n . replicate n) 1`, where `singleRandP :: Float -> IO Int` generates `1` with propability `p`. Also please stop updating the same question, if you have another question you can just make a new one.

Comment: already solved! Thanks :) I will think a lot before I ask a question next time!

Answer (score 1):

Because `drawFloat` returns a monadic type, you'll have to dive into the same monad in order to append:

```
import System.Random

drawFloat :: Float -> Float -> IO Float
drawFloat x y = getStdRandom (randomR (x,y))

appendRandom :: [Float] -> IO [Float]
appendRandom as = do
  val <- drawFloat 2 10
  return $ as ++ [val]

main = appendRandom [1, 2, 3] >>= print
```